# grep: Invalid content of \{\}

Tags: regex, grep

Im getting `grep: Invalid content of \{\}` when trying to run this:

```
grep -r '"new":\{.*:\\[.*\\].*\}' my_file.txt
```

Comment: Please explain your reasoning for that line.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm trying to find lists in a JSON string, exactly in those items thats have "new" index.

Comment: Grep defaults to basic regular expressions, and escaping `{}` makes them into special characters (delimiting a quantifier, like "5 times `x`": `x\{5\}`). For literal `{` and `}`, just don't escape them.

Comment: Also, you probably want a JSON aware tool such as jq for this, not grep.

Answer (score 1):

Without `-E` option you don't have to escape `{`.

Correct escaping would be only escaping `[`

```
grep -r '"new":{.*:\[.*].*}' my_file.txt
```

Comment: Or don't and just don't escape `{` and `}`.